# Website folder allows directory browsing - how to see images?

Tags: browser, image-viewer

There is a website which allows directory browsing and returns results as shown below (there are hundreds of images).

What's the easiest way to browse the images without clicking on every link?  *Preferably using only a browser so it could work anywhere.*

I could write some code to screen scrape and save but I figure there has to be an easier way.  Ideas?

```
Index of /wp-content/uploads/2017/01

[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
[DIR]   Parent Directory        -    
[IMG]   10126992_l-150x150.jpg  24-Jan-2017 17:14   7.6K     
[IMG]   10126992_l-200x130.jpg  24-Jan-2017 17:14   8.7K    
....many more...
```

Comment: Is the image filename a link?

Comment: @KenRatanachaiS yes they are all links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This site will extract all links from a web page.  Extract links and
   copy the resulting list of urls
   https://hackertarget.com/page-links-to
2. This free image hosting site will accept multiple Urls at the same
   time.  Paste in the list and choose upload.
   https://imgbb.com
3. You will then see all the images displayed

Answer (score 3):

What about using wget (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).  A direct link to the installer at the current time would be: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/gnuwin32/wget-1.11.4-1-setup.exe

Installs by default to: "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\".

Open a command prompt, CD to the above path and run:

```
wget -np -m http://www.example.com/images
```

Will fill the directory:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\www.example.com\images\"

Comment: Pretty good as far as simplicity, but I should have mentioned I was trying to do it in a browser since it's not a windows system.  If an online/browser answer doesn't pop up soon I'll accept yours (but will upvote you now regardless).

Answer (score 2):

I used [ThinGallery](https://github.com/gfwilliams/ThinGallery) together with [CORS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf) plugin for Chrome

1. Download ThinGallery to local folder
2. Open in text editor gallery.html and change baseURL string under loadAllImages function(line 442) to point it to "Index of /wp-content/uploads/2017/01" url
3. Add  img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous' line in getThumbFromFullImage function
4. Open gallery.html in Chrome browser and enable CORS plugin
5. It will show all pictures as browsable gallery

In case of local files [Local Image Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/local-image-viewer/lhlckkgdiojkapplglfeomlkjllphilo) extension allows you to view local folders with thumbnails as in windows explorer.

Or use this bookmarklet:
javascript:var%20sHTML="gallery<table%20border=0>";var%20y=0;for(x=0;x<document.links.length;x++){a=document.links[x].href;%20if%20(a.match(/jpe|jpeg|jpg|bmp|tiff|tif|bmp|gif|png/i)){sHTML+='<td%20style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px"><a%20target="_new"%20href="'+a+'"><img%20border="0"%20width="100"%20src="'+a+'">';%20if%20(!((x+1)%5))%20sHTML+=""}};this.innerHTML=sHTML+"";

Answer (score 1):

If they are all links then, why don't you use the famous [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/developers) Add-on on Firefox? (It's one of the reason why I still have Firefox installed actually). Especially, with the filters feature it's super handy.

[image: Just Right click and DownThemAll!]

Comment: I don't use FF but up-vote for good idea.  It has also prompted me to check Chrome add-ins.